# Typeorm. Why createQueryBuilder leftJoinAndSelect with condition and without condition but with where has different results?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, typeorm

Repo with example project: https://github.com/Fblfbl/backend-movies

Project on nest.js and typeorm (postgreSQL)

There are 3 entites:

1. Movies
2. Users
3. UserDetails (is movie favorite/watched for user)

UserDetails for movie(and for user) are created only after user add movie to favorite/watched
I want to get all movies for user with userDetails and without it by left join.

It works only when i use this repository method:

```
async findAllByUser(id: number) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('movie')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'movie.userDetails',
        'userDetails',
        `movie.id = userDetails.movieId AND userDetails.userId = ${id}`,
      )
      .getMany();
  }
```

And there it's example result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "test1",
        "genre": "test1",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 1,
            "isFavorite": false,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": false,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-25T19:29:18.510Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test2",
        "genre": "test2",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 2,
            "isFavorite": true,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": false,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-26T13:08:21.533Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "test3",
        "genre": "test3",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 3,
            "isFavorite": true,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": true,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-26T13:09:11.852Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "test4",
        "genre": "test4",
        "userDetails": null
    }
]
```

But if I use one of next two methods instead of the previous one:

```
  async findAllByUser(id: number) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('movie')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.userDetails', 'userDetails')
      .where(`movie.id = userDetails.movieId`)
      .andWhere('userDetails.userId = :userId', { userId: id })
      .getMany();
  }
```

```
async findAllByUser(id: number) {
    return this.find({
      relations: ['userDetails'],
      join: {
        alias: 'movie',
        leftJoinAndSelect: { userDetails: 'movie.userDetails' },
      },
      where: (qb) => {
        qb.where('userDetails.userId = :userId', { userId: id });
      },
    });
  }
```

I get this (no movie with id 4 which haven't userDetails for user):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "test1",
        "genre": "test1",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 1,
            "isFavorite": false,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": false,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-25T19:29:18.510Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test2",
        "genre": "test2",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 2,
            "isFavorite": true,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": false,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-26T13:08:21.533Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "test3",
        "genre": "test3",
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 3,
            "isFavorite": true,
            "isWatched": true,
            "isInWatchlist": true,
            "watchingDate": "2021-07-26T13:09:11.852Z",
            "userId": 1,
            "movieId": 3
        }
    }
]
```

All methods use left join, but why the result is different? Can you explain please

Answer (score 1):

I'm just seeing this and thinking it might be a little too late, but might as well answer for the next one that comes around. The differences between the two queries lie on which part of the expression. The first one is something like:

> "Find me *all* the movies in the `movies` table, and, from each movie, gather up the related `userDetails` that belong to the user with ID 1"

Note the condition being directly tied to the userDetail, and not the movie selection. Whereas the second one:

> "Find me *all* movies and *all* of their related userDetails, where the userId belonging to the userDetail equals 1

Now you can think of the movie + its userDetails being bundled up into one row of results, and then filtering over each row, keeping only those that have *at least* one userDetail whose userId equals 1.
I hope this clarifies this issue.